# How to add Android phone as a COM port in Windows 10 (via Bluetooth)?

Tags: windows, android, putty, bluetooth, com

My phone is Meizu M2, which I'd like to connect with my Windows 10 PC (via Bluetooth). I'm using an external bluetooth adapter for the PC.

There's an android app called "Arduino Bluetooth RC Car" (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=braulio.calle.bluetoothRCcontroller).

I wanted to test this app with my PC to see if it sends commands properly.

Here's what I did: I paired my phone with my PC via Bluetooth I installed Putty on my PC Putty requires information about COM port number, but when I go to Bluetooth settings (in Win10) I don't see any COM ports available. When I click "Add..." I don't have any device do add.

So how can I connect my Meizu M2 with a PC with COM Port connection?

Comment: Your phone needs to present a Bluetooth serial port to the PC in order for a COM port to appear on the PC. Most phones present only internet/network profiles to the PC and without your device manufacturer or firmware having intentionally supported your device acting as a Bluetooth serial device this will not work.